# Polymer dart element run on Ubuntu, but it doesn' t in chrome app on Android device

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, dart-polymer

I am trying to build a simple Chrome app with Dart and Polymer, based on Dart Editor sample "clickcounter". It runs on my Lubuntu Desktop, but it doesn't on my Android (4.2.2) device.

**polymer_chrome_app.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polymer chrome app</title>
    <!-- include the web_components polyfills with support for Dart. -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
    <!-- import the click-counter -->
    <link rel="import" href="clickcounter.html">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="polymer_chrome_app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Polymer chrome app</h1>
    <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>
    <div id="container_id">
      <click-counter count="5"></click-counter>
    </div>
 <script type="application/dart" src="polymer_chrome_app.dart"></script> 
    <script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" defer></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**polymer_chrome_app.dart**

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
void main() {
  initPolymer();
  print ("hello!");
}
```

**clickcounter.html**

```dart
<!-- import polymer-element's definition -->
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="click-counter" attributes="count">
  <template>
    <style>
      div {
        font-size: 24pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 140px;
      }
      button {
        font-size: 24pt;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <button on-click="{{increment}}">Click me</button><br>
      <span>(click count: {{count}})</span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="clickcounter.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**clickcounter.dart**

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
/**
 * A Polymer click counter element.
 */
@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  @published int count = 0;

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created() {
  }
  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
name: polymer_chrome_app
description: A sample Chrome packaged application
dependencies:
  chrome: any
  polymer: any  
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/polymer_chrome_app.html
    csp: true
- chrome
- $dart2js:
    csp: true
```

Any ideas on fixing this problem?

**EDIT**
A clarification: the chrome app runs, but the click-counter element isn't shown. No errors are thrown in javascript console.

**EDIT**
Dart version: 1.7.2
Polymer version: 0.15.1
Chrome version: 39.02171.59
For deploy I'm using:
CADT on device
cca on my laptop

Comment: what's the actual problem? I see a bunch of code, but no error of any kind. What behavior are you seeing and what behavior should you be expecting?

Comment: Which Chrome versions has your device? What Polymer version do you use? `any` doesn't always ensure you're using the latest version.

Comment: The most recent version is Polymer `0.15.1+5`.

Comment: What Dart SDK version are you using?

Comment: Which application do you use to deploy to android mobile?

Comment: I've created a github issue on the mobile-chrome-apps repo to track this (https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/451).  We don't test Dart Chrome Apps often, so its not unlikely that this is a problem with our toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Android stock browser is not supported by Polymer.

See

- https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html
- https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/202

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your android device is correctly connected.
2. Check if your application is completely deployed.

   - Which applicatino do you use ? 
     You need install Chorme App Developer Tool first.
3. Debug.
   run `chrome://inspect/#devices` and find out what the problem is.

Comment: 1.DONE
2.DONE
3.Only "hello!" are displayed in console log.

Comment: No error message are displayed on inspector console. Only "hello!".